# Memory-efficient subsetting of large data.table

Tags: r, memory, data.table, subset

I have a SQLite-db with a size of 11 GB and 16 GB of RAM (shared with OS and so on). I want to perform a subsetting method with data.table:

```
# database connection
con = dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"), dbname=sqlite_database)

# read table from database
inventory <- as.data.table(dbGetQuery( con,'select * from inventory'))

# subset table
unfulfilled_inventory <- inventory[period >= stableStateStart, .(period, articleID, unfulfilledQuantities, backlog, stock)]
```

Getting more RAM would be the cheapest way to solve this problem, but unfortunately this is not an option.

The inventory object has 127,500,000 rows with 6 variables. The inventory object has an allocated size in memory of 5.2 GB.

```
dim(unfulfilled_inventory)
[1] 127500000         6
```

Is there a way to do this subsetting in a more memory-efficient way? I tried building a vector for vector scanning, but it has the same result. Or is there a way to use swap space for this operation (I do not really care about speed).

Comment: Just to confirm, which object is `5.2GB` here? Also what does `dim(inventory)` result in?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only two I have in mind at the moment:

1. use `setDT` instead of `as.data.table`, you will save some memory when reading from db.
2. You can compute your condition on the database side as then use computed column in R:

```
sql = "SELECT *, period >= stableStateStart AS tmpcol FROM inventory"
inventory = setDT(dbGetQuery(conn, sql), key="tmpcol")
inventory[.(TRUE)]
```

3. Adding `ORDER BY tmpcol` to sql query may also help on `setDT(., key="tmpcol")` in later step.

Be sure to use data.table 1.9.6 - recently published to CRAN.